# Can my landlord keep my deposit for longer in case additional flea treatment is needed? (renting with pets)

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property

The pet clause in my tenancy agreement (AST) states that the landlord will keep part of my deposit (£300) for an additional 3 months, in case additional flea treatment is needed.

I'm perfectly happy with this arrangement and do not intend to challenge this, but I was wondering if they are legally able to do this.

I've tried to look into this and all I could find on the government's website was:

> Your landlord must return your deposit within 10 days of you both
>   agreeing how much you’ll get back

Which doesn't really explain whether agreeing that the additional £300 will be repaid 3 months later is legally allowed.

Additionally, as deposits need to be protected by a government-backed tenancy deposit scheme, does that mean that this £300 needs to be protected for an additional 3 months, or is our landlord allowed to just keep this in their bank account as the tenancy has already ended?

Comment: Not writing an answer since I don't know it for the UK, in switzerland they are allowed to keep deposits until they paid all bills. There are even court cases because landlords sometimes kept deposits for years.

Comment: The question may need to be more precise. "Agreeing that it will be repaid late" is perfectly legal; putting the clause in the agreement is perfectly legal (provided it's made clear). What is uncertain is whether the clause is legally enforceable. And I don't understand the last sentence; tenancy deposit schemes usually keep the deposit until both you and the landlord agree to its return, with the interest split between you, him and the scheme.

Comment: I would say that if it takes 3 months to find out if defleaing is needed then how can you agree on an amount until you figure out what the amount is?

Comment: @Tim, tenancy deposit schemes keep the full deposit until the amount to be returned is agreed on. In this case, some of it would be returned immediately, whilst the remaining £300 would be returned at a later date. I'm assuming this means the DTS would return our deposit minus £300 to us, and the remaining £300 to the landlord who would hold onto it for an additional 3 months (rather than the DTS keeping the remaining £300, as the tenancy has ended). My question is whether the landlord should protect the remaining £300 for those additional months.